# Wrong Behavior using Synonyms

Tags: solr, lucene, synonym

I have a problem using synonyms (Lucene 4.6.1) . These are my conf and test cases.

**SynonymFilterFactory configuration.**

```
Map<String,String> initialParams = Maps.newHashMap();
initialParams.put("synonyms","synonym.txt");
initialParams.put("ignoreCase","true");
initialParams.put("expand","true");
initialParams.put("format","solr");
initialParams.put("luceneMatchVersion",Version.LUCENE_40.toString());

SynonymFilterFactory synonymFilterFactory = new SynonymFilterFactory(initialParams);
```

**Synonyms.txt**

```
american league, al, a.l. , a/l
Cassius clay, Muhammad ali
```

**Test Cases for Text #1**

```
Text #1: The american League is on fire.
```

//Positive Cases (All working fine)

```
Assert.assertTrue(LuceneUtil.evaluate(t1, "al"));
Assert.assertTrue(LuceneUtil.evaluate(t1, "a.l."));
Assert.assertTrue(LuceneUtil.evaluate(t1, "a/l"))
```

//Negative Cases (Working fine)

```
Assert.assertFalse(LuceneUtil.evaluate(t1, "a.l.s"));
Assert.assertFalse(LuceneUtil.evaluate(t1, "a/l/s"));
```

//Not Working

```
Assert.assertFalse(LuceneUtil.evaluate(t1, "\"al capone\""));
```

Although I'm trying to create a phrase query "al capone", seems like lucene is querying with 2 terms al OR capone.

But with the synonyms list isn't happening since "Cassius Clay" is not matching "Cassius other words".

**Test Cases for Text #2**
//Working

```
Text #2: Muhammad ali is the best
Assert.assertFalse(LuceneUtil.evaluate(t2, "\"Cassius other words\""));
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does `LuceneUtil.evaluate` do?

Comment: It just create the query parser and execute the search. Both Index and parser are using the same analyzer.
return memoryIndex.search(parser.parse(escapedKeywords)) > 0.0f